# Optimización operación condicional

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Amig@s, vengo en busca del conocimiento y creatividad de la comunidad.

Tengo una función la cual realiza seteo de variables de acuerdo a ciertas condiciones; si bien, se cumple con el objetivo que busco, visualmente (no me extrañaría que funcionalmente también), se ve horrible, asqueroso, ya que nunca he sido amigo de anidar condiciones en una cascada interminable.

Les adjunto el horror :'D

```
const setValueGloss = (id: number, input: string, value?: any): void => {
        const reasonSelected = (input === 'reasons') ? value : formEgreso.reasons
        const aux = {
            idPayment: id,
            idReason: reasonSelected?.id,
            reasonName: reasonSelected?.name,
            originReason: states.combos.motivoEgresoMultiple.find((item: any) => item.codigo === reasonSelected?.id)
        }

        if ((aux.idReason === 4100 && (aux.idPayment === 9 || aux.idPayment === 10))) setFormEgreso({ ...formEgreso, gloss: aux.reasonName, [input]: value })
        else {
            if (aux.idReason === 5100 && (aux.idPayment === 11 || aux.idPayment === 12)) setFormEgreso({ ...formEgreso, gloss: (aux.idPayment === 11) ? aux.originReason?.glosaEgreso1 : aux.originReason?.glosaEgreso2, [input]: value })
            else {
                if (aux.idReason === 600 && (aux.idPayment === 14 || aux.idPayment === 15)) setFormEgreso({ ...formEgreso, gloss: (aux.idPayment === 14) ? aux.originReason?.glosaEgreso1 : aux.originReason?.glosaEgreso2, [input]: value })
                else {
                    if ((aux.idPayment === 9)) setFormEgreso({ ...formEgreso, gloss: aux.originReason?.glosaEgreso1, [input]: value })
                    else {
                        if ((aux.idPayment === 10)) setFormEgreso({ ...formEgreso, gloss: aux.originReason?.glosaEgreso2, [input]: value })
                        else setFormEgreso({ ...formEgreso, gloss: '', [input]: value })
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Como pueden ver, esos `if` son el problema; obviamente no puedo manejarlo con `switch` debido a que requiero *N id's* para condicionar las acciones.

Si a alguien se le ocurre una forma más sutil, elegante y eficiente de realizar esto me lo hacen saber!!

Saludos y feliz término de año a tod@s! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Un aporte que quiero dar es que cuando hay varias condiciones anidados yo los guardo en `variables` y despues las utilizo, de esta forma

```js
var cond1 = false;
var cond2 = false;
var cond3 = true;

switch (true) {
  case cond1:
      console.log('cond1 true');
      break;
  case cond2:
      console.log('cond2 true');
      break;
  case cond3:
      console.log('cond3 true');
      break;
  default:
      break;
}
```

Cosa que en cada `var cond` iria tu condicion, porque esto devuelve un `booleano`

```
var cond1 = aux.idReason === 4100 && (aux.idPayment === 9 || aux.idPayment === 10)
```

Ademas en el `switch` estoy poniendo un `true` para que se ejecute solamente los `cases` sin depender de `switch('este valor')`.

Si no quieres utilizar el `switch`, puedes usar simplemente los `if` de esta forma

```js
var cond1 = false;
var cond2 = false;
var cond3 = true;

if ( cond1 )
    console.log('cond1 true');
if ( cond2 )
    console.log('cond2 true');
if ( cond3 )
    console.log('cond3 true');
```

- **OJO:** En ambos casos es necesario especificar muy bien las condiciones para que trabajen de forma independiente y esto es muy importante en especial en el `switch` para que no se salte un `case` y pueda dar errores futuros

Comment: Fue un aportazo, no tenía idea que podías pasarle múltiples condiciones a un switch. Gracias por el dato!

Comment: @PauloUrbanoRivera en cierta manera me equivoque al responder que se puede poner multiples condiciones en un `switch`, asi que editare mi respuesta para poder hacer lo que quieres

Comment: Esto lo digo ya que en el `switch(x)` solo puede existir un dato y nada mas pero en los `cases` multiples datos

Answer (score 0):

Los `else` que te vi usar en el código los retengo superfluos, ya que usas un `else` para contener una condición `if / else` y bastaría colocar varios `if` ya que estos no se ejecuta si su condición no se cumple y al proseguir el código controla la condición del próximo `if`. El `else` se debe utilizar solo en caso de que específicamente quieras hacer algo en caso de que la condición especificada en el `if` sea falsa.

Ejemplo:

```
if (aux.idReason === 4100 && (aux.idPayment === 9 || aux.idPayment === 10)) {
    setFormEgreso({ ...formEgreso, gloss: aux.reasonName, [input]: value })
} else if (aux.idReason === 5100 && (aux.idPayment === 11 || aux.idPayment === 12)) {
    setFormEgreso({ ...formEgreso, gloss: (aux.idPayment === 11) ? aux.originReason?.glosaEgreso1 : aux.originReason?.glosaEgreso2, [input]: value })
} else if (aux.idReason === 600 && (aux.idPayment === 14 || aux.idPayment === 15)) {
    setFormEgreso({ ...formEgreso, gloss: (aux.idPayment === 14) ? aux.originReason?.glosaEgreso1 : aux.originReason?.glosaEgreso2, [input]: value })
} else if (aux.idPayment === 9) {
    setFormEgreso({ ...formEgreso, gloss: aux.originReason?.glosaEgreso1, [input]: value })
} else if (aux.idPayment === 10) {
    setFormEgreso({ ...formEgreso, gloss: aux.originReason?.glosaEgreso2, [input]: value })
} else setFormEgreso({ ...formEgreso, gloss: '', [input]: value })
```

Comment: Al parecer no fui suficientemente claro. Como indique en la pregunta, no puedo utilizar switch ya que las acciones requieren varias condiciones, y switch solo recibe una expresion como parámetro. En cuanto a los else, posiblemente tengas algo de razón, pero ten en cuenta que el último else deja campos vacíos si no se cumple ninguna condición anterior, algo como el default de switch, por lo que no sé que tanto pueda prescindir de los else

Comment: Ya la actualicé, espero que lo que quería decir sobre los *else* ahora sea más comprensible con el ejemplo de código que utilicé. En realidad, hace lo mismo, pero esa es la sintaxis correcta según [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp)

Comment: Cierto! Gracias por la observación :D

Comment: También en tu último y penúltimo *if*